# Исправить ошибки в коде Pascal

Tags: pascal

Даны два массива А(i) и B(i). Создать массив C(i), каждый элемент которого будет равен наименьшему каждой пары элементов из А и В (элементы массива А и В вводить с клавиатуры).

Мой код:

```
program zadaca46;
uses crt;
const n=20;
var 
a:array[1..n] of byte;
b:array[1..n] of byte;
c:array[1..n] of byte;
i:integer;
Begin
    begin
      writeln('vvedite elementi massiva A');
       For i:=1 to n do
        Readln(A[i]:4);
    end;
    Begin
        Writeln('vvedite elementi massiva B');
        For i:=1 to n do
        readln(B[i]:4);
    end;
    begin
        writeln('massiv C');
         For i:=1 to n do
           Begin
             c[i]:=min(a[i],b[i]);
             write(c[i]:4);
           end;
    readkey;
    end;
    end.
```

Comment: @Oleg1997, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Что за ошибка? И что такое min? Оно есть в том диалекте паскаля, который вы используете?

Comment: @Oleg1997, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Слово `program` можно не писать.

```
uses crt;
const n=20;
var 
a:array[1..n] of byte;
b:array[1..n] of byte;
c:array[1..n] of byte;
i:integer;
```

Почему стоит `byte` а не `integer`?

Comment: ошибку уже исправил.Программа не работала бы если вводились бы отрицательные числа.

Comment: Теперь все работает?